# Component identification, on USB 2.0 data lines

Tags: identification, components, repair

The component i'm trying to identify is on the usb 2.0 D+ and D- lines of a nintendo switch, its got two ground connections and has the letters DUG on it.

Can anyone identify this component?

[image]

Comment: Probably an ESD suppressor. TVS of some sort.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe [this](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpd2e1b06.pdf) is it, it has the markings of DUG.
[image]

[image]
Source: www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpd2e1b06.pdf

Comment: This was really helpful, saved me ordering a load just to check if it was faulty or not, i was hoping it would be though as it now only leaves the cpu that has the short.